# Displaying PDFs to authenticated users only and preventing downloading

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, pdf, iframe

I have an app which presents authenticated users with a list and by selecting the item it will display a PDF.

1. I need to prevent the user from accessing the PDFs using direct URLs if they are unauthenticated - 
   I have tried a HTTP Handler which works but then I have issues displaying the document in a iframe
2. Display a PDF to a user across all devices (smartphone/tablet/PC) without allowing to  download (Android seems to auto download) - 
   Used Google docs embed link but the HTTP Handler above prevented the document being displayed and displayed the code view of the login page.
3. Using an iframe with iOS seems to have issues and is not allowing me to scroll unless. (Seems like it might be reported bug)

I think displaying using the google doc embed link might be the best to prevent downloading (Android issues) and allow scrolling on iOS but I just need to prevent the webserver displaying the PDFs if the user isnt authenticated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My answer is about the question 1. Have you tried to use **[Authorize]** attribute to method which responsible for downloading?

Comment: @IskabderRaimbayev can you give a bit more details as to what you mean by this? I had initially tried using a web config file in the directory for the PDFs but this was ignored, and after further investigation I discovered that static files would be served prior to reading this, so the HTTP Handler was suggested. Thanks